# Qual a melhor maneira de desfazer um merge com elementos em staged e modfy com conflitos?

Tags: git

Fiz um merge desnecessário com uma branch, agora tenho vários elementos em staged e não mesclados pelo fato de exitirem conflitos. Qual a melhor maneira de reverter este merge e deixar a branch no ultimo commit antes desta ação indesejada?

Comment: Bom, conversando com colegas chegou-se a conclusão que, o procedimento é normal, volta-se os stageds com git reset HEAD <nome-dos-arquivos> e quando todos estiverem em modify, basta dar um checkout . "se estiver na raiz" que sua branch irá estar no ultimo commit antes da ação indesejada.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assumindo que o merge não gerou nenhum commit (já que há conflitos). Na raiz do seu repositório, digite

```
git reset .
```

Isso irá remover todas as mudanças que estão *staged*, colocando-as de volta na lista de *modified*.

Em seguida, reverta todas as modificações:

```
git reset HEAD --hard
```

Isso irá reverter todas as modificações nos arquivos modificados. Note que se você tinha alguma outra modificação, ela também será perdida.

Se o merge adicionou arquivos novos no repositório, então você pode "limpá-los" através do `git clean`. Novamente da raiz do repositório:

```
git clean -xdf
```

Como sempre, cuidado quando usar o `git clean` já que ele pode apagar arquivos que você gostaria de ter. Você pode usar a opção `n` em fez de `f` para listar os arquivos que serão apagados.

Comment: Os elementos que estavam em modfy estão como não monitorados, o que fazer com estes?

Comment: Editei a resposta para cobrir este cenário.

Comment: Muito obrigado!!! Resolveu o meu problema mesmo! Não me preocupei com os arquivos apagados pois estou com vinculado à uma branch remota, assim eu deu pull e trouxe tudo de novo. Muito obrigado amigo!

Answer (score -1):

Um merge pode ser cancelado com

```
git merge --abort
```

De acordo com o Pro GIT Book https://git-scm.com/book/pt-pt/v2/Ferramentas-do-Git-Advanced-Merging